# How to run deployed Angular application

Tags: angular

I am facing a rather strange behavior when I am trying running the app after deploying it. I build my app with the following command:

```
ng build --watch=true
```

Then in my index.html I change:

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="/dist/">
```

and it's not loading anything. But if I start the app from within the dist folder without any changes to dist/index.html it works fine.

I used to be able to run it starting outside of the dist folder, for some reason it's not working. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You don't change base href to dist. Dist is minifed and compiled angular project. So If you want to run your app on the server you copy all the content of the dist directory and serve it, you don't need anything else on the server

Comment: But I was able to run it by navigating to index.html in the  root folder and serving the app from /dist subfolder. That's why I was changing base to /dist/. However, that is not working anymore.

Comment: Try "." as href.

Comment: Nope, the same.